# How to save a value inside a fragment shader to use it later?

Tags: javascript, webgl, fragment-shader

I want to save a calculated value from fragment shader in some variable ,so that I would be able to use it next time.

Currently, I am preparing a image using a huge algorithm and I want to save it to some vec4 and , once requested again , I want to just get that vec4 and should say

`gl_FragColor = vec4(previously saved variable)`

This question is related to another [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178723/how-to-apply-multiple-image-processing-in-webgl-with-two-or-more-separate-color) which is also asked by me , but I feel that if this question has a answer then I can easily crack the other one.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fragment shaders in WebGL write to 1 of 2 things. Either (1) the canvas to (2) the attachments of a framebuffer. The attachments of a framebuffer can be textures. Textures can be used as inputs to a shader. Therefore you can write to a texture and use that texture in your next draw.

Here's an example

```js
var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
}
`;
var fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
  // just grab the middle pixel(s) from the texture
  // but swizzle the colors g->r, b->g, r->b
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(.5)).gbra;
}`;

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
var program = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);

var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
// we don't need to look up the texture's uniform location because
// we're only using 1 texture. Since the uniforms default to 0
// it will use texture 0.

// put in a clipspace quad
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
  -1, -1,
   1, -1,
  -1,  1,
  -1,  1,
   1, -1,
   1,  1,
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// make 2 1x1 pixel textures and put a red pixel the first one
var tex1 = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA,
              gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([255, 0, 0, 255]));
var tex2 = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex2);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA,
              gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

// make a framebuffer for tex1
var fb1 = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb1);
// attach tex1
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
                        gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1, 0);
// check this will actually work
if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !==
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  alert("this combination of attachments not supported");
}

// make a framebuffer for tex2
var fb2 = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb2);
// attach tex2
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
                        gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex2, 0);
// check this will actually work
if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !==
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  alert("this combination of attachments not supported");
}

function render() {
  gl.useProgram(program);
  // render tex1 to the tex2
  
  // input to fragment shader
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1);  
  
  // output from fragment shader
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb2);  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  
  // render to canvas so we can see it
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  // input to fragment shader, the texture we just rendered to
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex2);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  
  // swap which texture we are rendering from and to
  var t = tex1;
  tex1 = tex2;
  tex2 = t;
  
  var f = fb1;
  fb1 = fb2;
  fb2 = f;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

The sample above puts red in a texture. It then renders that texture by swizzling the color. Green goes to the red channel, Blue goes to the green channel, Red goes to the Blue channel.

I makes 2 textures and attaches them to 2 framebuffers.

First iteration

```
tex1 = red
tex2 = 0,0,0,0
render to fb2
tex2 is now blue (because red was copied to blue)
render tex2 to canvas (canvas is now green because blue is copied to green)
switch which textures we're rendering to
```

Second iteration

```
tex1 = blue (was tex2 last time) 
tex2 = red  (was tex1 last time)
render to fb2 (was fb1 last time)
tex2 = green (because blue is copied to green)
render tex2 to canvas (canvas is now red because green is copied to red)
switch which textures we're rendering to
```

Comment: I have understood framebuffers with your example above . Many thanks for that. However, this line in second iteration `tex2 = green (because blue is copied to green)` is confusing , because if we are swapping framebuffers , how can we expect output from fragment shader i.e. `gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb2);  `to be assigned to tex2 directly?

Comment: Also, is there any way to know the color value (RGBA) in each texture by using the WebGLTexture interface, that would help me understand and debug things in a better way, now I am just guessing things :(

Comment: `fb2` had `tex2` attached to it using `gl.framebufferTexture2D`. `texture2D(u_texture, ...)` is reading from `tex1` and `gl_FragColor = ..` is writing to tex2 because it's the `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` to the currently bound framebuffer `fb2`

As for your second question if you bind `fb2` then `gl.readPixels` will return pixels from `tex2`. If you bind `fb1` then `gl.readPixels` will return pixels from `tex1`. If you bind `null` as the current framebuffer then `gl.readPixels` will return pixels from the canvas (except for the issue that WebGL clears the canvas depending on the settings).

Answer (score 0):

Fragment shader executes per fragment(pixel).And as any other shader it cannot store values by default, as you would expect in regular programming language.
There are several ways to do what you want:
You can use [imageLoad/Store](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) ,which allows you to read and write data from shader into image.[Image](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt) uses GL textures as memory storage.What is good about it is that you can store and load numeric data without losing precision when using images because texture filtering is disabled when accessing texture data via image.

Another way to store and read data in shaders is using buffers.Uniform buffers,or since GL4.3 [Shader storage buffers.](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object).
SSBO allows to read and write huge amount of data.It is really up to you to decide which of those to use for storing and retrieving your data in the shaders.Some people say texture memory access is faster on some hardware.From my experience,using SSBO vs image load store,I haven't found significant difference in performance on Nvidia GPUs.

In your scenario I would probably go with Image Load/Store.Because you can use the same UV indexing into image data as you do into sampled texture.

Also,I don't really know what version of OpenGL you are using ,but to use these extensions you must use GL4.2 and GL4.3.

Comment: I am using WebGL 1.0, which follows OpenGL ES 2.0 , I think. Do I have all these luxury of GL4.2 and GL4.3?

Comment: Unfortunately for you,you don't.

Comment: ok, then how can I persist a vec4 so that I can access it later, any idea?

Comment: @SubhasishDash: emit it to gl_FragColor and render to a texture attached-to-FBO. Then for the next step pass in that texture as usual; the texture in its pixels contains the values you stored in the previous step. In case you want to emit multiple values there's the WEBGL_draw_buffers extension, a nice overview on how to use it can be found at http://www.dartgamedevs.org/2013/07/multiple-render-targets-and-deferred.html

Comment: @SubhasishDash  just make sure you have texture attachment filtering GL_NEAREST and no mipmaps.

Comment: Okay thanks @datenwolf and Michael for your valuable suggestions, could you please take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178723/how-to-apply-multiple-image-processing-in-webgl-with-two-or-more-separate-color) , this is the problem statement and I can't find a way to persist the texture after applying the Palette properly for the 2nd palette . Maybe a pseudocode from your side will be of a great help . Thanks.

Comment: The question is tagged `WebGL` making this answer arguably offtopic